# Show Value in pop up window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to show form value in pop up window which is open after clicking submit button. how can i show form value in pop up window after clicking submit button. My Form is below

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="example" action="" method="post">
<table width="257" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Father Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="fname" id="fname" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Show Value" /></center></td>    
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: on formsubmit call some jquery and read form contents. Do some research. https://api.jquery.com/submit/  AND   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Get data using input id and set form delay for submit and read javascript and jquery basic concept on w3 school

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>   

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<form name="example" action="" method="post" id="example">
<table width="257" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Father Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="fname" id="fname" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><center> <input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Submit" /></center></td>    
  </tr>

</table>
</form>

    <div id="dialog" style="display: none" align="center">
          <label>Name :</label><span id="show_name"></span>
          <br>
         <label>Father Name :</label><span id="show_fname"></span>

    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>


        $(function () {
           $("#dialog").dialog({
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                title: "User Details",
                width: 300,
                height: 150,
            });
            $("#btnShow").click(function (e) {

               e.preventDefault();
                var name=$("#name").val();
                var fname=$("#fname").val();

                $("#show_name").html(name);
                $("#show_fname").html(fname);

               $('#dialog').dialog('open');

             setTimeout(function() {
                 $("#example").submit();
              }, 3000);

           });


        });


</script>
```

Comment: I want to open pop up window after clicking submit button where name and father show

Comment: yes i try but here show value in alert box . but i want to open new pop up window after clicking submit button and show form value in new pop up window

Answer (score 0):

at first, your button is type="submit", but if you want just show values you need set type="button", and call some function in onclick attribute, what will show your values,like that:

**button**

```
<input type="button" name="button" value="Show Value" onclick="myFunction()"/>
```

and you need add **js script** for show values:

```
function myFunction(){
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    alert(name+' '+fname)
}
```